# Select Tag Helper confusion

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I have this

```
public class EventListViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and in controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
List<EventListViewModel> eventList = this.eventStructureBLL.EventListGetBy("it");
return View(eventList);
}
```

and in View this

```
@model List<Common.DAL.ViewModels.EventListViewModel>
```

what is the Select Tag Helper correctly

```
<select asp-for="??" asp-items="???"></select>
```

Comment: you need to set some key value in asp-for and in asp-items you can use your Model. Check this for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Check this blog I hope it will help you http://blog.vivensas.com/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-basic-binding/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting something and posting it back requires something to bind that to. Since it'll be a single item, you'd need something like:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int SelectedEventId { get; set; }
}
```

That property, then, is what you would bind to:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedEventId" ...></select>
```

Then, you need to pass your list of options as well, which should be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Since you already have a view model, for the property you're binding to, add this as a property there as well:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public int SelectedEventId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EventOptions { get; set; }
}
```

To fill this in your action:

```
model.EventOptions = this.eventStructureBLL.EventListGetBy("it").Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = x.Description
});
```

Then, of course, this model will be what you pass to your view:

```
return View(model);
```

And, in the view:

```
@model FooViewModel
```

Finally, your select tag would be:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedEventId" asp-items="@Model.EventOptions"></select>
```